# How do i subtract two 2d arrays of Arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, arraylist

I have arraylist

```
ArrayList <double[][]>deltaedge=new ArrayList<double [][]>();
```

which contain 2  2d double datatype arrays i have to subtract suppose array no 0 from array no 1 and again store result in array no 0.

Comment: So what's your question. where's the difficulty?

Comment: This code won't compile.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Why? A `double[][]` is an `Object[]`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Yes it will. (I've just tried it.) What makes you think it won't?

Comment: My bad.. I didn't notice array.. One shouldn't comment 30 seconds after waking up from mobile.

Comment: What do you mean by subtracting one array from the other?  Do you mean finding all elements that are in the first but not the second  (set difference)? Or do you mean like matrix subtraction?

Comment: 1) Create a new 2d-array. 2) Use a nested for-loop and the "minus" operator (`-`) to substract each element of the array. 3) Use the methods `get` and `set` on the list to get the arrays and set the new array. 4) Post a question if you get stuck with something *specific*.

Answer (score -1):

```
double[][] one=deltaedge.get(0);
double[][] two=deltaedge.get(1);
double[][] three=Subtraction(one,two);//call this method

deltaedge.set(0, three);// set the result to zero position
// subtract method
public double[][] Subtraction(double[][] one, double[][] two) {
    double[][] C = new double[one.length][one.length];
    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
            C[r][c] = one[r][c] - two[r][c];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

Comment: The right idea.  But what if the arrays aren't 2x2?

Comment: I just written the skeleton code...you can change the code according to your situation dynamically...

Comment: It just seems a shame to post an answer that's only half right.  You could easily use `one.length` and `one[0].length` in place of `2`, as limits on `r` and `c`, so that this would work for arrays of any size.

Comment: As a general note, using anything but `array.length` as the loop index bound will undermine HotSpot's range check elimination and other optimizations.

Comment: @DavidWallace `one[r].length` is preferred due to the above concern.

Comment: i told u previously i just written the skeleton code